# Is an extraction of the mnemonic string possible if wallet and corresponding passphrase are in possesion?

Tags: mnemonic-seed

My problem is that I have access to my wallet and I am able to access it with Electrum because I have the passphrase but I somehow misplaced the seed.

Is it possible to decrypt/extract and obtain the wallets mnemonic seed string with said access?

Any time donated towards this issue will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From your Electrum toolbar click on "Wallet" and then select "Seed". A new window will open asking you to enter your password, do that correctly and you will see your seed words if you wallet has any (meaning if it is a standard HD wallet not an imported one).

Comment: The problem is that this wallet in question wasn't created with Electrum. I used [Ian Colemans BIP32 Tool](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/)

Comment: "I used Ian Colemans BIP32 Tool" still if you imported that seed (BIP39) into your Electrum you should be able to obtain it the same way.

Comment: Best to use the optional password too not just the mnemonic. Engrave each on cryptosteel, store in two separate secure locations.